# Persistence.xml is that optional?

Tags: java, jpa

When i create a jpa project, is persistence xml optional?

I was using spring JPA the sample projects did not have one..

Comment: Look at the spring contexts, you can define all the data from persistence.xml in Spring configuration files.

Answer (score 3):

It's only possible if your project is Spring-based. Otherwise you need at least a minimal META-INF/persistence.xml.

Comment: if i add a persistence xml, and use maven plugin... how does it process the annotated classes... i mean how does jpa know about the annotated classes if the persistence xml has no explicit class deifinition. Does it modify the persistence xml when creating the jar?

Comment: By default, JPA provider will scan all classes in the jar that  contains META-INF/persistence.xml for @Entity